# Grouping OR clause with DATEDIFFS in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, where-clause, datediff

I have a sql table.  We'll call it 'table'.  I'm trying to do a select with a few WHERE clauses.  I need the last where clause to be an OR.  Normally, I just do this:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE 1=1
AND (firstName='tom' OR lastName='jones')
```

However, on this particular query, I need the two sides of the OR to be DATEDIFFS. I'm trying to grab all rows where the difference between the timestamp and "NOW" is either greater than 10 hours or less than 0 hours.  So, what I've got now, which errors, is this:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE 1=1
AND (
      DATEDIFF(hh, table.timestamp, GETDATE()) > 10
    OR
      DATEDIFF(hh, table.timestamp, GETDATE()) < 0
    )
```

I have tried several different versions of what I have above and nothing seems to be working.  Any help would be much appreciated!  I'm sure I've just been staring at it too long and it's something stupid.

A new more detailed query:

Yeah, there's two left joins in my query which is probably what's making a difference here.  I was trying to keep my examples simple, but it wound up biting me.  Here's a more relevant query:

```
SELECT
  tblCheckoutActivity.rid,  
  tblCheckoutActivity.checkedOutUser,
  tblCheckoutActivity.checkedOutTime,
  tblCheckoutInventory.serial,
  tblCheckoutInventory.unit,
  tblCheckoutInventory.tag,
  tblCheckoutUsers.firstName,
  tblCheckoutUsers.lastName
FROM
  tblCheckoutActivity
LEFT JOIN
  tblCheckoutInventory
ON 
  tblCheckoutActivity.scannerID = tblCheckoutInventory.SID
LEFT JOIN
  tblCheckoutUsers
ON
  tblCheckoutActivity.checkedOutUser = tblCheckoutUsers.badgeID
WHERE
  tblCheckoutActivity.checkedInTime Is Null 
AND 
  tblCheckoutInventory.site='San Francisco'
AND
  (
    DATEDIFF(hh, tblCheckoutActivity.checkedOutTime, GETDATE()) > 10
  OR
    DATEDIFF(hh, tblChecckoutActivity.checkedOutTime, GETDATE()) < 0
  )
ORDER BY tblCheckoutUsers.lastName
```

Comment: Which implementation? SQLServer?

Comment: What version of SQL Server?  What is the datatype of `timestamp`?

Comment: The error that I get is this:
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 25
Incorrect syntax near '<'.

Comment: The timestamp is data type DATETIME

Comment: Is that all your query?, cause your error says line 25, what if you call table `[table]`?

Comment: I assume your table is not really called `table` - but is your column called `timestamp` ? That's a reserved word and may be problematic.

Comment: Putting brackets around the table name doesn't change anything.  I get the same error.

Comment: my column is actually called checkedOutTime

Comment: There has got to be more to this, cause your query looks fine, just ran one equivalent to yours just to check... can you show more of your query without showing too much? Like you said, I am willing to bet its a simple oversight caused by what I call too-much-querying. (I don't really call it that.)

Comment: Just to be sure: Do you have timestamps in the future in that table? If not then the <0 will never be true. It could equal 0 but won't be less than zero.

Comment: @Eddy, if that were the case it would at least run.  Currently his code errors out.

Comment: VERY strange assuming thaqt timestamp DATETIME, try out just for interest  DATEDIFF(hour, table.timestamp, GETDATE()) Basically 'hour' instead 'hh', also try to use simply timestamp not table.timestamp

Comment: Based on all the comments I am putting my money on a mismatch in your brackets. Can you do a quick count on how many ('s and )'s you have in your query.

Comment: Eddy +1, he missed something anyway

Comment: @Eddy - I have checked my brackets and they are fine.  I'm going to look at the rest of my query to see if there's something else going on.

Comment: @abe miessler I know. It's just something perculiar that caught my eye.

Comment: Could you please post WHOLE SQL Script

Comment: @Dex: Could you ensure thaqt SQL you've posted is truly on the 25 line ?

Comment: typo in this table name - `tblChecckoutActivity`

Comment: I just updated my original question with my full query at the bottom.

Comment: @slothrop - damn...I feel like a moron now.

Comment: The typo was the problem.  Facepalm.  Sorry everyone.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Welcome - and at least you didn't have `WHERE 1=1` in your real query ;-)

Comment: lol...yeah, I was just trying to keep it simple for the question.  The lesson learned is to copy and paste my code.  I have to say that posting a question on StackOverflow only to find out that a typo was the problem is humbling.

Comment: Next question - does DATEDIFF (hh, startdatetime, enddatetime) do what you intend it to?  Examples: (a) diff between 5:59 and 6:01 returns 1; (b) diff between 6:01 and 6:59 returns 0.  Remember it gives you the number of "boundaries between whole hours" that are spanned by your startdatetime and enddatetime.

Comment: @Dex ahh well a good lesson for next time is to post a query that actually reproduces the problem :)

Comment: @Dex: Rewrite the `DATEDIFF(hh, tblCheckoutActivity.checkedOutTime, GETDATE()) > 10` tosomething like `tblCheckoutActivity.checkedOutTime < DATEADD(hh,10,GETDATE())` so an index of `checkedOutTime` can be used.

Comment: @Dex: Are you using the timestamp datatype for the timestamps?

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is somewhere else.  I just ran this with no errors:

```
with temp as
(
select 1 as id,        CAST('10/31/2011' as DATETIME) as timestamp
UNION
SELECT 2,        CAST('11/1/2011' as DATETIME)
UNION
SELECT 3,        CAST('11/2/2011' as DATETIME)
UNION
SELECT 4,        CAST('11/3/2011' as DATETIME)
UNION
SELECT 5,        CAST('11/6/2011' as DATETIME)
UNION
SELECT 6,        CAST('11/8/2011' as DATETIME)
)

SELECT *
FROM temp
WHERE 1=1
AND (
      DATEDIFF(hh, timestamp, GETDATE()) > 10
    OR
      DATEDIFF(hh, timestamp, GETDATE()) < 0
    )
```

Are you showing us an abbreviated version of your query?  Is there code before this query that is missing from your example?

Comment: Yes...there are two left joins and another table involved.  I am sure that's where the complication is occurring.  The query runs fine without my DATEDIFF OR clause though.

Comment: Hi Abe - I'm new to CTEs.  Generally speaking, what are the primary differences between using CTEs via the `WITH` clause and simply creating and using temporary tables?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the timestamp datatype, then that's your problem. You can't do a DATEDIFF comparison between a DATETIME and a timestamp.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE 
      DATEDIFF(hh, table.timestamp, GETDATE()) > 10
UNION
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE 
      DATEDIFF(hh, table.timestamp, GETDATE()) < 0
```

quick and dirty but it should work

Comment: For the sake of performance, I cannot run two selects on the same data like that.  I appreciate your suggestion, but it won't work for my situation.  Thanks!